# Decompose $5^{1985}-1$ into factors

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Decompose the number $5^{1985}-1$ into a product of three integers, each of which is larger than $5^{100}$.

We first notice the factorization $x^5-1 = (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$. Now to factorize $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ we get $$(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1) = x^4+(a+b)x^3+(ab+2)x^2+(a+b)x+1 = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$ implies $a+b = 1,ab+2 = 1$. Thus, $$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = (x^2+\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)x+1)(x^2+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)x+1).$$ Is it possible to continue from this approach because now the factors I have aren't integers or is there a better way?

Comment: what made you come to this question? is it an excercise from a book?

Comment: Write 5=4+1 and expand.

Comment: @almagest Do you mean like $x^5-1 = (x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1)x$?

Comment: One factor is $5^{397}-1$.  But according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E1985-1+factor),  The remaining factors are $2^2$, $11$, $71$, $146891$, $1043801929$ and $7768438039$ which unlikely fulfill all your requirements.

Comment: @NgChungTak According to Pari-GP, $(5^{397}-1)/4$ is not prime, so other factors can come from this number

Comment: @egreg Yes, it can [further factorize](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E397-1+factor).  The factors $11$, $71$ and $146891$ seem belong to $\frac{5^{1985}-1}{5^{397}-1}$

Comment: @Max This was an IMO question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would try [Aurifeuillian factorization](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/number_theory/aurifeuillian.pdf) here.

Let $f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ be the fifth cyclotomic polynomial. The Aurifeuillian stuff says that $f(5x^2)$ factors into a product as follows
$$
f(5x^2)=\left(25 x^4-25 x^3+15 x^2-5 x+1\right) \left(25 x^4+25 x^3+15 x^2+5
   x+1\right).
$$
Call those two factors on the RHS $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$.

Your number is
$$
\begin{aligned}
5^{1985}-1&=(5^{397}-1)f(5^{397})\\
&=(5^{397}-1)g_1(5^{198})g_2(5^{198}),
\end{aligned}
$$
and this fits the bill.

Comment: I thought of Aurifeuillian factorization, but did not expect that this works here. Great solution!

Comment: I thought Aurifeullian not come from a proper name, did not know that is because of J.F.A. Aurifeuille which I hear for the first time. Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer, nice reference! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

See here

http://factordb.com/index.php?query=5%5E1985-1

for the partial factorization of $5^{1985}-1$. There are three factors with $200$ digits or more. No idea how the factors can be expressed. Multiply one of the factors with the smaller factors to get a decomposition of the desired form.

Answer (score 3):

A low-tech solution.
$1985=5\cdot 397$, and $ \Phi_5(x) $ is a palyndromic polynomial, decomposable as
$$ \left(x^2-\frac{x}{2}+1\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}x^2 \tag{1}$$
[or as](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865758/simplification-of-1xx2x3x4/1865771#1865771):
$$(x^2+3x+1)^2-5x(x+1)^2 \tag{2}$$
that with $x=5^{397}$ is the difference of two squares, $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, with both $a-b$ and $a+b$ being $>5^{100}$. The claim hence follows from
$$ 5^{5\cdot 397} = (5^{397}-1)\cdot\Phi_5\left(5^{397}\right).\tag{3} $$

Comment: How do you go from $$ \left(x^2-\frac{x}{2}+1\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}x^2$$
to
$$(x^2+3x+1)^2-5x(x+1)^2?$$

Comment: Inspired guess.

Comment: Good job. Unless I'm mistaken, substituting $x=5t^2$ into $(2)$ leads to a difference of squares and exactly the Aurifeuillian factorization.