# Factorise the number $5^{2015} - 1$ into three positive factors such that each is greater than $5^{200}$

Tags: number-theory

Factorise the number $5^{2015} - 1$ into three positive factors such that each is greater than $5^{200}$

I don't really know how to do this. Is inequality involved?
Bonus question: can the same be done for $5^{2017} - 1$

Comment: I could post a variant of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865896/11619), but that would make this a duplicate :-). 2015 has a friendlier factorization than 1985, so it seems to me (see lhf's answer) that cyclotomic tricks will suffice. OTOH, if you want three factors $>5^{400}$, then Aurifeuillian is the way to go. And, no, I don't see a way to use Aurifeuillian factors with $5^{2017}-1$.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the factorization of $x^{2015}-1$ into [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial):
$$
x^{2015}-1 = \Phi_{1} \Phi_{5} \Phi_{13} \Phi_{31} \Phi_{65} \Phi_{155} \Phi_{403} \Phi_{2015} 
$$
and write
$$
5^{2015} - 1 = ABC
$$
with
$$
A=(\Phi_{1} \Phi_{5} \Phi_{13} \Phi_{31} \Phi_{65} \Phi_{155})(5),
\quad
B=\Phi_{403}(5),
\quad
C=\Phi_{2015}(5)
$$
You still need to check that $A,B,C > 5^{200}$. The degrees of the polynomials are $215,  360, 1440$, which is a good indication (but not proof) that this is true.

You cannot do this trick for $2017$ because $2017$ is prime and
$$
x^{2017}-1 = \Phi_{1} \Phi_{2017} 
$$
(but of course this does not mean that $5^{2017}-1$ cannot be factored)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221051/growth-of-cyclotomic-polynomials.