# Prove that $ N = \frac{5^{125} - 1}{5^{25} - 1} $ is a composite number.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that $$ N = \frac{5^{125} - 1}{5^{25} - 1} $$ is a composite number.

I just proved it will be a natural number with

quotient= $5^{100} +5^{75}+5^{50}+5^{25}+1$

But I do not know how to factorise it for proving it composite.

Comment: Hint: try to factor the terms

Comment: Ya , I tried but wasn't able to do

Comment: This is a repetition of this post: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314779/prove-that-n-frac5125-1525-1-is-a-composite-number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314779/prove-that-n-frac5125-1525-1-is-a-composite-number)

Comment: How about you edit this question and include exactly what it is you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization), it's $(5^{50}+5^{38}+3\times5^{25}+5^{13}+1)(5^{50}-5^{38}+3\times5^{25}-5^{13}+1)$.